# manually label spec types via metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

> Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
>              rspec-rails 3 will no longer automatically infer an example group's spec type    from the file location. You can explicitly opt-in
>   to this feature using this    snippet:
>
> ```
>    RSpec.configure do |config|
>      config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
>    end
> ```
>
> If you wish to manually label spec types via metadata you can safely
>   ignore    this warning and continue upgrading to RSpec 3 without
>   addressing it.

as I don't like the `configure` solution than how can I actually **manually label spec types via metadata** ?

Comment: Why don't you like the `configure` solution? Are you on Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set arbitrary metadata on examples or groups by passing a hash to `describe`, `it` etc

For example:

```
describe SomeController, :type => :controller do
  ...
end
```

Has the same effect as relying on `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` (assuming the file is in spec/controllers)

The different types of specs are:

- Model specs: `type: :model`
- Controller specs: `type: :controller`
- Request specs: `type: :request`
- Feature specs: `type: :feature`
- View specs: `type: :view`
- Helper specs: `type: :helper`
- Mailer specs: `type: :mailer`
- Routing specs: `type: :routing`

For more information, see [Rspec's documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure).